# Can I edit the context menu of a text field (not Explorer context menu)?

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I want to add an entry to the context menu of a text field, eg:

[image: text field context menu]

I have an AutoHotkey executable that will put highlighted text into the clipboard, then execute a Google search in Chrome with the clipboard. I would like a registry addition that gives me a single-click in the menu, that runs that executable. I have achieved this in the Explorer context menu (for processing of files with third-party applications, etc), but I have found no mention anywhere of the ability to change this specific menu.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks how to edit the context menu for an Edit control,
and provides an image showing an Edit control context menu, present
while renaming a file in Explorer.

One approach would be to show a custom context menu,
when an Edit control is right-clicked,
or when an Edit control is focused and the `AppsKey` is pressed.

The AutoHotkey script below provides such functionality
for Explorer (tested on Windows 7), it replicates
the Edit control menu and adds a button that opens the selected
text in the default web browser.

Note: The Explorer address bar also uses an Edit control,
however, this is taken into account by the script.

```
;AutoHotkey script for:
;windows - Can I edit the context menu of a text field (not Explorer context menu)? - Stack Overflow
;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827324/can-i-edit-the-context-menu-of-a-text-field-not-explorer-context-menu/41343741#41343741

;see also:
;contextmenu - Can I add a custom paste option to the windows text editing context menu? - Stack Overflow
;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370415/can-i-add-a-custom-paste-option-to-the-windows-text-editing-context-menu/41343891#41343891

;tested on Windows 7

GroupAdd, WinGroupFolder, ahk_class CabinetWClass ;explorer
#IfWinActive, ahk_group WinGroupFolder
$RButton Up:: ;explorer - custom Edit control menu
$AppsKey:: ;explorer - custom Edit control menu
;#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
;$RButton Up:: ;notepad - custom Edit control menu
;$AppsKey:: ;notepad - custom Edit control menu

;STAGE - create menu if not already created
if !vIsReady
{
    Menu, EditMenu, Add, &My Item, MyItem
    Menu, EditMenu, Add ;------------------------------
    Menu, EditMenu, Add, &Undo, EditUndo
    Menu, EditMenu, Add ;------------------------------
    Menu, EditMenu, Add, Cu&t, EditCut
    Menu, EditMenu, Add, &Copy, EditCopy
    Menu, EditMenu, Add, &Paste, EditPaste
    Menu, EditMenu, Add, &Delete, EditDelete
    Menu, EditMenu, Add ;------------------------------
    Menu, EditMenu, Add, Select &All, EditSelectAll

    VarSetCapacity(vPos1, 4), VarSetCapacity(vPos2, 4)
    VarSetCapacity(vPos1X, 4), VarSetCapacity(vPos2X, 4)
    vIsReady := 1
}

;STAGE - perform certain checks, if any of them fail
;then let hotkeys perform their normal function,
;start by stating that, so far, the checks have not failed
vRet := 1

;check - if active control is an Edit/RichEdit control
if vRet
{
    WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
    ControlGetFocus, vCtlClassNN, ahk_id %hWnd%
    ControlGet, hCtl, Hwnd, , %vCtlClassNN%, ahk_id %hWnd%
    WinGetClass, vWinClass, ahk_id %hCtl%
    if !(SubStr(vWinClass, 1, 4) = "Edit") && !(SubStr(vWinClass, 1, 8) = RichEdit)
    vRet := 0
}

;check - if a right-click was performed, the control
;under the cursor must be the active control
if vRet && InStr(A_ThisHotkey, "RButton")
{
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, vPosX, vPosY, , hCtl2, 3
    if !(hCtl2 = hCtl)
    vRet := 0
}

;check - the Edit control must be for a file icon and not the address bar
if vRet
{
    ;hWndParent := DllCall("user32\GetParent", Ptr,hCtl, Ptr)
    hWndParent := DllCall("user32\GetAncestor", Ptr,hCtl, UInt,1, Ptr) ;GA_PARENT := 1
    WinGetClass, vWinClassParent, ahk_id %hWndParent%
    if (vWinClassParent = "ComboBox")
    vRet := 0
}

;if a check has failed, then let hotkeys perform their normal function
if !vRet
{
    if InStr(A_ThisHotkey, "RButton")
        SendInput {Click right}
    if InStr(A_ThisHotkey, "AppsKey")
        SendInput {AppsKey}
    Return
}

;STAGE - if clicked Edit control, menu will appear
;relative to cursor coordinates retrieved earlier,
;if pressed AppsKey, menu will appear in centre of Edit control
if !InStr(A_ThisHotkey, "RButton")
{
    WinGetPos, vPosX, vPosY, vPosW, vPosH, ahk_id %hCtl%
    vPosX += vPosW/2, vPosY += vPosH/2
}

;STAGE - retrieve information from Edit control
;and disable menu items accordingly
;Undo - check undo status (is undo available)
;Cut - check text selection > 0
;Copy - check text selection > 0
;Paste - check clipboard not empty
;Delete - check text selection > 0
;Select All - always available

SendMessage, 0xC6, 0, 0, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;EM_CANUNDO := 0xC6
vOptU := ErrorLevel ? "En" : "Dis" ;1=undo available/0=undo not available
ControlGet, vText, Selected, , , ahk_id %hCtl%
vOptT := StrLen(vText) ? "En" : "Dis"
vOptC := StrLen(Clipboard) ? "En" : "Dis"

Menu, EditMenu, % vOptU "able", &Undo, EditUndo
Menu, EditMenu, % vOptT "able", Cu&t, EditCut
Menu, EditMenu, % vOptT "able", &Copy, EditCopy
Menu, EditMenu, % vOptC "able", &Paste, EditPaste
Menu, EditMenu, % vOptT "able", &Delete, EditDelete

;STAGE - get Edit control character positions
;(unfortunately showing the custom menu ends the rename mode,
;we get the Edit control character positions in order to restore them later)
SendMessage, 0xB0, &vPos1, &vPos2, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;EM_GETSEL := 0xB0
vPos1 := NumGet(vPos1), vPos2 := NumGet(vPos2)

;STAGE - show menu
CoordMode, Menu, Screen
Menu, EditMenu, Show, %vPosX%, %vPosY%
Return

;==============================

;STAGE - replicate standard Edit control menu items
;(or perform custom menu function)
;(unfortunately showing the custom menu ends the rename mode,
;so the Edit control has to be put into rename again,
;and the character positions restored)
EditUndo:
EditCut:
EditCopy:
EditPaste:
EditDelete:
EditSelectAll:
MyItem:

;STAGE - enter rename mode again
IfWinActive, ahk_group WinGroupFolder
{
    SendInput {F2}
    Loop, 20
    {
        ControlGetFocus, vCtlClassNN, ahk_id %hWnd%
        if (SubStr(vCtlClassNN, 1, 4) = "Edit")
            break
        Sleep 50
    }
    if !(SubStr(vCtlClassNN, 1, 4) = "Edit")
    {
        MsgBox % "error"
        Return
    }
    ControlGet, hCtl, Hwnd, , % vCtlClassNN, ahk_id %hWnd%

    ;STAGE - restore character positions
    if !InStr(A_ThisLabel, "SelectAll") && !InStr(A_ThisLabel, "MyItem")
    {
        vRet := 0
        Loop, 100
        {
            SendMessage, 0xB1, vPos1, vPos2, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;EM_SETSEL := 0xB1
            SendMessage, 0xB0, &vPos1X, &vPos2X, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;EM_GETSEL := 0xB0
            vPos1X := NumGet(vPos1X), vPos2X := NumGet(vPos2X)
            if (vPos1 = vPos1X) && (vPos2 = vPos2X)
            {
                vRet := 1
                break
            }
            Sleep 50
            if !vRet
            {
                MsgBox % "error"
                Return
            }
        }
    }
}

;STAGE - perform standard Edit control menu functions
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "Undo")
    SendMessage, 0x304, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;WM_UNDO := 0x304
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "Cut")
    SendMessage, 0x300, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;WM_CUT := 0x300
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "Copy")
    SendMessage, 0x301, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;WM_COPY := 0x301
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "Paste")
    SendMessage, 0x302, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;WM_PASTE := 0x302
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "Delete")
    SendMessage, 0x303, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;WM_CLEAR := 0x303
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "SelectAll")
    SendMessage, 0xB1, 0, -1, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;EM_SETSEL := 0xB1

;STAGE - actions to take if user chooses custom menu item
if 0 ;this comments out the 6 lines below
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "MyItem")
{
    vText := "My String"
    ;ControlSend, , % vText, ahk_id %hCtl% ;use SendInput instead since capitalisation can be unreliable
    SendInput {Raw}%vText%
}

;STAGE - actions to take if user chooses custom menu item
if InStr(A_ThisLabel , "MyItem") && !(vText = "")
{
    MsgBox, 0x40003, , % "Choose 'Yes' to search for:`r`n" vText
    IfMsgBox Yes
    {
        vUrl := "http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" UriEncode(vText)
        Run, "%vUrl%"
        ;Run, chrome.exe "%vUrl%"
    }
}

Return
#IfWinActive

;==================================================

;URL encoding - Rosetta Code
;https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/URL_encoding#AutoHotkey

; Modified from https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/75390-ahk-l-unicode-uri-encode-url-encode-function/?p=480216
UriEncode(Uri)
{
    VarSetCapacity(Var, StrPut(Uri, "UTF-8"), 0)
    StrPut(Uri, &Var, "UTF-8")
    f := A_FormatInteger
    SetFormat, IntegerFast, H
    While Code := NumGet(Var, A_Index - 1, "UChar")
        If (Code >= 0x30 && Code <= 0x39 ; 0-9
            || Code >= 0x41 && Code <= 0x5A ; A-Z
            || Code >= 0x61 && Code <= 0x7A) ; a-z
            Res .= Chr(Code)
        Else
            Res .= "%" . SubStr(Code + 0x100, -1)
    SetFormat, IntegerFast, %f%
    Return, Res
}

;==================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

I will describe editing a file's menu first, and then editing an Edit control's menu afterwards.

File's menu:

If you know how to safely use RegEdit,
creating this registry entry, will add the option 'My Script' to the right-click context menu for all files:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\My Script\command
(Default)   REG_SZ  "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\My Script.ahk" "%1"
```

Clicking on the menu item will launch the script.

If you want to do something to the file that was clicked, it's path can be retrieved via:

```
vPath = %1%
```

To operate on more than one file at the same time requires a shell extension, which is more complicated.

Edit control's menu:

The context menu in your image is an Edit control's context menu.
To change *that* menu would be more difficult. When you rename a file, you are editing text on a small Edit control.

To 'add' a menu item, the simplest method would be to replace the entire menu with your own custom context menu. With your custom menu item on top, and you would probably want to recreate the Undo/Cut/Copy/Paste/Delete/Select All items that operate on the Edit control. Using `ControlGet, vText, Selected` to recreate the Copy function for example. You would also need to capture right-clicks via the RButton hotkey, and use `ControlGetFocus` to check if an Edit control was in focus, and `MouseGetPos` to check if an Edit control was under the cursor. So there would be some work involved. Regarding capturing right-clicks, see the link below, where you would replace LButton with RButton. Good luck!

[Is it possible to catch the close button and minimize the window instead? AutoHotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882844/is-it-possible-to-catch-the-close-button-and-minimize-the-window-instead-autoho/41325497#41325497)

Comment: Good point, thank you. You might also want to check for when AppsKey is pressed and the window is a folder/desktop, and check if the focused control is an Edit control. (Although granted only *clicking* the control was mentioned in the question.)

Comment: Doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: The fundamental sentence of the question I believe is 'I have found no mention anywhere of the ability to change this specific menu.' The title also says
'Can I edit the context menu of a text field'. It shows the text field (Edit control) in the process of being renamed.
I believe that I have answered that question in the second part of my answer.
I provided supplementary information as the question was unclear,
and as it could be useful to others.

Comment: As regards 'What if select edit control menu using keyboard?' clicking
or keypressing to focus an icon is irrelevant, it is only during the rename
phase that the Edit label is visible, and only then via right-click or AppsKey,
very possibly other keypresses/clicks, can you access the Edit control menu. I have dealt
with those 2 scenarios.

Comment: @vafylec: But you wrote: "to check if an Edit control was under the cursor". NO. I put item in Explorer in rename mode, move cursor and select context menu using keyboard. Eureka, cursor is not under edit control. So this part of your answer is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, some things I just assume the programmers will realise as obvious. For an AppsKey keypress, you don't need MouseGetPos, but for a right-click you do. Anyhow you're quite right that for the keypress, MouseGetPos is not required. Unless I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

;Menu Google Search Autohotkey script: select any text in any text edit field, then press
AppsKey & RButton::
^+g:: ; or press Ctrl+Shift+g
Menu,GoogleSearch,Add,Search with Google,GoogleSearch
Menu,GoogleSearch,Show
return

GoogleSearch:
{
Send, ^c
Sleep 50
Run, http://www.google.com/search?q=%clipboard%
Return
}

Comment: Please format your answer appropriately. You can use formatting options available when editing your post. Use the link provided in the edit form to see what formatting options are available to you.